# calculating weekly occupancy given daily capacity and booking

Tags: statistics, regression, percentages, descriptive-statistics, beta-function

I aim to model weekly room occupancy as percentage but observe a very "bipolar" (?) distribution (majority of rooms either have 0% or 100% occupancy). This made me wonder, if I possibly do something wrong in the way I calculate the weekly occupancy percentage for a room. The following shows a few example observations for room with ID = 1 (there are 1000s of rooms):

```
Room Id Cal Date    Week Number Booking RoomFree
1   16/12/2019  51  0   1
1   17/12/2019  51  0   1
1   18/12/2019  51  0   1
1   19/12/2019  51  0   1
1   20/12/2019  51  0   1
1   21/12/2019  52  1   0
1   22/12/2019  52  1   0
1   23/12/2019  52  1   0
1   24/12/2019  52  1   0
1   25/12/2019  52  1   0
1   26/12/2019  52  1   0
1   27/12/2019  52  1   0
1   28/12/2019  1   1   0
1   29/12/2019  1   1   0
1   30/12/2019  1   1   0
1   31/12/2019  1   1   0
1   01/01/2020  1   0   0
1   02/01/2020  1   0   0
1   03/01/2020  1   0   0
1   04/01/2020  2   0   1
1   05/01/2020  2   0   1
1   06/01/2020  2   0   1
1   07/01/2020  2   0   1
1   08/01/2020  2   0   1
1   09/01/2020  2   0   1
1   10/01/2020  2   0   1
```

The same data as picture with week 1 highlighted red:

[image]

I think it is important to note, that bookings (Column Booking) can span over several weeks (e.g. 21/12/2019-31/12/2019). Some weeks also have not the full capacity of 7 days (e.g. week 1 highlighted red).

The way I calculate weekly occupancy percentage per week is by adding RoomFree and Booking, which gives me the capacity:

```
Capacity = Booking + RoomFree
```

So in week 1 that would be 4. The occupancy percentage is then simply calculated by dividing the sum of Booking by the capcity. So for week 1 that would be 4/4 = 1.0 (aka 100%).

Is this calculation flawed and thus results in this very "bipolar distribution" I observe (automatic binning by seaborn - granularity of percentages larger):

[image]

It appears that if I use "monthly grain" the distribution is more uniform.

I hope this makes sense and apologies for bothering proper mathematicians which such a possibly mundane and simple problem. Thanks in advance for any help.

PS:

Maybe it is worth considering the fact that different capacities allow for different occupancy percentages?

[image]

Comment: Your calculation is correct. As you mentioned, the possible occupation values are limited by the observation time. Since rooms are often booked for several days your results are similar to the daily occupation (which can only be 0 or 1). Consider a longer timeframe for more precise results.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I cannot use longer time periods given the requirements.

Comment: Depending on your application it might be useful to only consider the extreme cases resulting in a Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: @Christian I was wondering if it is (statistically) sound if I just impose a threshold (e.g. 0.5) and use logistic regression or the like. Guess this is what you are hinting at?

Comment: Sounds reasonable